# Control Label of Contour Lines in `contour()`

Tags: r, contour

I am using `image()` and `contour()` to create a "heatmap" of probabilities - for example:

[image]

I was asked to change the labels such that they "do not overlap the lines, and the lines are unbroken." After consulting `?contour()`, I tried changing to `method = "edge"` and `method = "simple"`, but both fail print the labels (although the lines are unbroken), and cant seem to find posts regarding similar issues elsewhere.

[image]

Any advice on how to manipulate the labels to appear adjacent to (not on top of) unbroken lines would be much appreciated. I would prefer base R but also would welcome options from more flexible packages or alternative base R functions.

Minimal code to recreate example figure is here:

```
# Generate Data
Rs <- seq(0.02, 1.0, 0.005)
ks <-  10 ^ seq(-2.3, 0.5, 0.005) 
prob <- function(Y,R,k) { 
  exp(lgamma(k*Y+Y-1) - lgamma(k*Y) - lgamma(Y+1) + (Y-1) * log(R/k) - (k*Y+Y-1) * log(1+R/k))
}
P05 <- matrix(NA, ncol = length(ks), nrow = length(Rs))
for(i in 1:length(Rs)) {
  for(j in 1:length(ks)) {
    P05[i,j] <- 1 - sum(prob(1:(5 - 1), Rs[i], ks[j]))
  }
}
colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("grey25", "grey90"))
lbreaks <- c(-1e-10, 1e-5, 1e-3, 5e-3, 1e-2, 2e-2, 5e-2, 1e-1, 1.5e-1, 1)

## Create Figure
image(Rs, ks, P05,
      log="y", col = rev(colfunc(length(lbreaks)-1)), breaks = lbreaks, zlim = lbreaks,
      ylim = c(min(ks), 2), xlim = c(0,1))
contour(Rs, ks, P05, levels = lbreaks, labcex = 1, add = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easy(ish) way to do this in ggplot, using the geomtextpath package.

First, convert your matrix to an x, y, z data frame:

```r
df <- expand.grid(Rs = Rs, ks = ks)
df$z <- c(P05)
```

Now plot a filled contour, and then `geom_textcontour`. By default the text will break the lines, as in `contour`, but if you set the vjust above one or below zero the lines will close up as they don't need to break for the text.

I've added a few theme and scale elements to match the aesthetic of the base graphics function. Note the text and line size, color etc remain independently adjustable.

```
library(geomtextpath)

ggplot(df, aes(Rs, ks, z = z)) +
  geom_contour_filled(breaks = lbreaks) +
  geom_textcontour(breaks = lbreaks, color = 'black', size = 5,
                   aes(label = stat(level)), vjust = 1.2) +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1, 2), 
                expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rev(colfunc(9)), guide = 'none') +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0.5),
        axis.ticks.length.y = unit(3, 'mm'),
        plot.margin = margin(20, 20, 20, 20))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `contour` function is mostly written in C, and as far as I can see, it doesn't support the kinds of labels you want.

So I think there are two ways to do this, neither of which is very appealing:

1. Modify the source to the function.  You can see the start of the labelling code [here](https://github.com/r-devel/r-svn/blob/16608beee41970b8e0e183a78444431babe41abc/src/library/graphics/src/plot3d.c#L1585).  I think you would need to rebuild R to incorporate your changes; it's not easy to move a function from a base package to a contributed package.
2. Draw the plot with no labels, and add them manually after the fact.  You could add them using `text()`, or produce an output file and use an external program to edit the output file.